# Regex: how to get the text between a few colons?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

So, i have a lot of strings like the ones below in my database:

**product1:1stparty:single_aduls:android:**

**product2:3rdparty:married_adults:ios:**

**product3:3rdparty:other_adults:android:**

I need a regex to get only the text after the product name and before the device category. So, in the first line I'd get **1stparty:single_aduls**, in the second **3rdparty:married_adults** and in the third **3rdparty:other_adults**. I'm stuck and can't find a way to solve that. Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

As a regular expression, you can use:

```
select regexp_extract('product1:1stparty:single_aduls:android:', '^[^:]*:(.*):[^:]*:$')
```

This returns every after the first colon and before the penultimate colon.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(val, r"^.*?:|:[^:]+:$", "") AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

This approach removes either the leading `...:` or trailing `:...:` from the column, leaving behind the content you want.  Here is a demo showing that the regex replacement is working:

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can also use standard [`split`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#split) function and access result array element by index, which is quite clear to read and understand.

```
with a as (
  select split('product1:1stparty:single_aduls:android:', ':') as splitted
)
select splitted[ordinal(2)] || ':' || splitted[ordinal (3)] as subs
from a
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below example

```
with your_table as (
  select 'product1:1stparty:single_aduls:android:' txt union all
  select 'product2:3rdparty:married_adults:ios:' union all
  select 'product3:3rdparty:other_adults:android:' 
)
select *, 
  (
    select string_agg(part, ':' order by offset)
    from unnest(split(txt, ':')) part with offset 
    where offset in (1, 2)
  ) result
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? does it work for you?! consider voting up if it helped. and accept if you feel appropriate